# Chartjs add and remove data

Tags: jquery, chart.js

hope someone could help me. Based on this sample https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html i would like to implement the "add" and "remove data" but with a limit of 20 labels/months/years (or control this limit) and not with random data. below the code i've changed but i have some issue also when remove the data and add again.

```
var MONTHS = ['Year 11', 'Year 12', 'Year 13', 'Year 14', 'Year 15', 'Year 16', 'Year 17', 'Year 18', 'Year 19', 'Year 20'];
        var barChartData = {
            labels: ['Year 1', 'Year 2', 'Year 3', 'Year 4', 'Year 5', 'Year 6', 'Year 7', 'Year 8', 'Year 9', 'Year 10'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Label 1',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [
                    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
                ]
            }, {
                label: 'Label 2',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [
                   11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
                ]
            }]

        };

        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                    }
                }
            });

        };

        document.getElementById('addData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (barChartData.datasets.length > 0) {
                var month = MONTHS[barChartData.labels.length % MONTHS.length];
                barChartData.labels.push(month);

                for (var index = 0; index < barChartData.datasets.length; ++index) {
                    barChartData.datasets[0].data[10] = 500;
                    barChartData.datasets[1].data[10] = 200;
                }
                window.myBar.update();

            }
        });

        document.getElementById('removeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            barChartData.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

            barChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                dataset.data.pop();
            });

            window.myBar.update();
        });/years
```

MANY THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code, your problem is about adding data,so I fixed it, please in adding function in your loop I mean that.

```
for (var index = 0; index < barChartData.datasets.length; ++index) {
                barChartData.datasets[0].data[10] = 500;
                barChartData.datasets[1].data[10] = 200;
            }
```

replace those

```
barChartData.datasets[0].data[10] = 500;
barChartData.datasets[1].data[10] = 200;
```

with this

```
barChartData.datasets[index].data.push( Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) );
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but i need to add custom data not random (for each label), and with a limit to 20 labels. here is a demo link [link](http://divinethemes.eu/test/chart/charts_demo.html). i would like to display the custom data for the first 10 years, then a user can click the button to view the next year (untill year 20) or remove. however thanks